# While loop together with foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm really stuck trying to resolve what should be quite simple.

I Have this

```
<?php 

$json = json_decode('{
                      "33540116":
                                 {"person":
                                           {"name":"John", "age":"36"}},
                      "33541502":
                                 {"person":                                                                                      
                                           {"name":"Jack", "age":"23"}}
                     }
        ');

 $id = array('33540116', '33541502');


foreach($id as $id) {

        echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
        echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';


        }
?>
```

So the code is decoding a json string then using foreach to echo each result.

This json file is rather large and I'm only interested in certain records that match the id's stored in a mysql table.

To do this I have replaced the id array string above with mysql select statement.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{
                      "33540116":
                                 {"person":
                                           {"name":"John", "age":"36"}},
                      "33541502":
                                 {"person":                                                                                      
                                           {"name":"Jack", "age":"23"}}
                     }
        ');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$id = array($row['id']);

foreach($id as $id) {

            echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
            echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';


            }
?>
```

Although this works, it only gives me 1 result. 
What I really need is to loop through the results.
Unfortunately I don't know how to construct a while loop together with foreach.

I will greatly appreciate your assistance.

UPDATE (extra question)

Thanks everyone. You have helped me solve the problem.

However, I have another question that relates to this matter.

I mentioned above that I merely wanted to echo the results. 
But this isn't exactly true.
What I really want to do is update the same mysql table with the results retreived from the json file.

I have a table called people with fields id, name and age.

How can I update this table with these results?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` only fetches one row at a time. You can use a `while` loop to continue fetching rows. The `mysql_fetch_array` function returns `false` once the whole result set has been fetched, so that will cause the `while` loop to terminate as desired.

Also, I removed the `foreach` loop on `$ids`. Since there will only be one element in the array it's unnecessary to put the code in a loop.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{
                      "33540116":
                                 {"person":
                                           {"name":"John", "age":"36"}},
                      "33541502":
                                 {"person":                                                                                      
                                           {"name":"Jack", "age":"23"}}
                     }
        ');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people");

while ( ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) ) {
    $id = $row['id'];

    echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
    echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = array($row['id']);

    foreach($id as $id) {
                echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
                echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This will only fetch **one row** from the database.

If you want to fetch more than one row, you have to call [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) in a loop :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Work with the current row
}
```

In your case, you'd have something like this :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
    echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need foreach loop the while is just enough

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people");
$id = array($row['id']);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $json->$row['id']->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
   echo $json->$row['id']->person->{'age'}. '<br />';

}
```

Comment: Thanks gyus. It worked. I ended up dropping the foreach as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, you shouldn't be using foreach($id as $id) since you are using the same variable for both. Instead it should be foreach($ids as $id). Secondly, you can get a list of the ids and echo out the correct json values as follows

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{
                      "33540116":
                                 {"person":
                                           {"name":"John", "age":"36"}},
                      "33541502":
                                 {"person":                                                                                      
                                           {"name":"Jack", "age":"23"}}
                     }
        ');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people");

$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

foreach($ids as $id) {

            echo $json->$id->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
            echo $json->$id->person->{'age'}. '<br />';


            }
?>
```

Hopefully that will solve it