# Update mysql table with data from json

Tags: mysql, json

I recently asked this question. [While loop together with foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687496/while-loop-together-with-foreach)

My problem was resolved with this

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM people");
    $id = array($row['id']);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo $json->$row['id']->person->{'name'}. '<br />';
       echo $json->$row['id']->person->{'age'}. '<br />';

    }
```

Currently this code only echo's the result set. 
What I really want to do is replace this echo with mysql update query. 
That will update the same table used in the select query.

This table called people has fields id, name and age.

How can I update this table with these results?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE people SET name='".$json->$row['id']->person->{'name'}."' && age='".$json->$row['id']->person->{'age'}."'");
```

Although I would suggest [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) rather than mysql_ functions

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately it did not work. Name field get's updated with 0 and age field is not affected at all.

Comment: Check your $json object. You haven't posted the code for it in the question so I can't help you any more right now. Above is the correct syntax.

Comment: Hi Calum. The code is on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687496/while-loop-together-with-foreach with my original question.